# PostgreSql ¿Està el servidor en ejecución en el servidor "192.168.0.113" y aceptando conexiones tcp/ip en el puerto 5432?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, centos, puertos, virtualbox

Primero que todo estoy usando virtualbox y tengo dos máquinas montadas con **CentOS 6**. Cada máquina tiene el adaptador de red configurado como "**adaptador puente**". Una maquina me sirve como el servidor de datos y la otra como servidor de aplicaciones.

Lo que necesito hacer es poder conectarme desde el servidor de aplicaciones al servidor de datos por medio de psql. Instalé `postgresql-server` en la mv de datos y `postgresql`(cliente) en la mv de aplicaciones.

Modifiqué el archivo `pg_hba.conf` con el siguiente parámetro:

```
host   all   all   192.168.0.113/24   md5
```

Y el archivo `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Además detuve el `iptables` para estar seguro de que no había ninguna regla que me impidiera la conexión. El puerto 5432 está abierto en el servidor de datos y el puerto 80 está abierto en el de aplicaciones

Para probar la conexión uso el comando:

```
psql -h 192.168.0.114 -U trewa -W gonce
```

Pero cada vez me tira el mismo error. No sé si debo cambiar algo en virtualbox o hay alguna otra configuración necesaria. Espero su ayuda por favor. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa por ejemplo, durante la instalación no pide nombre de usuario y contraseña para el usuario con privilegios de administración, algo que MySql si hace por defecto, ¿ y ahora, cómo me conecto al postgres?

Lo primero que debemos hacer es crear un usuario con permiso de superadministrador, es sencillo:

1. Primero nos autenticamos como root

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Pasamos a ser el usuario postgres, el cual se crea cuando instalamos postgres

   ```
   su postgres
   ```
3. Creamos el usuario nuevo con permisos de super administrador

   ```
   createuser -s -P nombre_usuario
   ```

El otro inconveniente que encontré fue que sólo me podía autenticar localmente desde la PC donde instalé el postgres y necesitaba que desde cualquier PC de la misma subred del lab se puedieran autenticar. Solución:

1. Primero debemos decirle que no escuche peticiones solamente desde el localhost, para eso editamos el fichero ubicado en `/etc/postgresql/8.3/main/postgresql.conf`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/postgresql/8.3/main/postgresql.conf
   ```

   Una vez que abrimos el archivo ubicamos la siguiente línea:

   `#listen_addresses = ‘localhost’`

   Sustituimos esa línea por la siguiente:

   `listen_addresses = ‘*’`

   Asi escuchará peticiones desde las direcciones permitidas en el fichero `pg_hba.conf`
2. Ahora debemos decirle en el fichero `pg_hba.conf` cuales son las direcciones ip autorizadas a conectarse al server

   sudo nano /etc/postgresql/version de tu posgret/main/pg_hba.conf

   Si queremos que escuche desde una subred entera, agregamos la siguiente línea al final

   ```
    host    all     all     10.35.12.0/24   md5
   ```

   Ahí estamos diciendo que para todas las bases de datos(primer all), todos los usuarios que intenten loguearse(segundo all) desde los Ip 10.35.12.1 al 10.35.12.254 se pueden loguear y se usará md5 .

   Si en vez de la subred solamenmte nos interesara que se logueen desde el IP 10.35.12.26:

   ```
    host all all 10.35.12.26 255.255.255.255 trust
   ```

   Y si quisiéramos que desde cualquier PC de la UCI se  logueen :

   ```
    host all all 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 md5
   ```

   Luego reiniciamos el postgres para que coja la configuración que le hemos dado:

   ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 restart.
   ```

Bueno, hasta aquí sesolví lo que necesitaba,opcionalmente si quieres administrar el server de Postgres desde la web puedes instalar el paquete phppgadmin

`sudo apt-get install phppgadmin`

Luego para acceder desde la web lo haces con `http://ip_servidor/phppgadmin` , debes haber instalado el Apache para poder acceder por la web.

Nota: Si al intentar acceder desde la web el server nos dice que no encuentra la direccion `/phppgadmin` debemos decirle al Apache que cargue el fichero de configuración del phppgadmin, para eso:

Editamos el fichero de configuración del Apache

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache/apache2.conf
```

Y le decimos que incluya al fichero de configuración del phppgadmin, para eso le añadimos la siguiente línea al final:

`Include /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf`

y reiniciamos el Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

También existe un cliente para Postgres llamado PgAdmin, para instalarlo debes instalar el paquete pgadmin3 en la PC desde la cual deseas administrar el server.

Si en el mismo server tendrás una aplicación programada con php y desde la misma necesitas acceder al postgres, debes instalar los siguientes paquetes:

php5, php5-pgsql(soporte de php para postgres), apache2(servidor web Apache), para ello ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get install php5  php5-pgsql apache2
```

Espero que les ayude.